# Unable to authenticate via LDAP to directory (Active Directory) with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security, ldap

I'm using:
- Spring 3.1.3

And the problem is I'm unable to connect with the Active Directory via LDAP using valid credentials.

i don't know if is caused by a malformed pattern  or a configuration issue about userdn or url's rootDn. Although , at first glance , it seems that everything is correct.

This is my current spring security config file:

```
...

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="ldapAuthProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

       <bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
      <constructor-arg>
        <bean id="bindAuthenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <property name="userDnPatterns">
               <list><value>sAMAccountName={0}</value></list>
            </property>
        </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

    <bean id="contextSource" 
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
         <constructor-arg value="ldap://remotehost:port/OU=My%20Company,dc=domain,dc=subdomain"/>
         <property name="userDn" value="CN=managerUserCN,OU=Users,OU=Test Accounts,OU=My Company,dc=domain,dc=subdomain/>
         <property name="password" value="thePass"/>
    </bean>

...
```

*I have replaced the real urls, organizations, groups, etc by descriptive data

*It's a requeriment searching by **sAMAccountName**.

And the NamingException throwed by doAuthentication:bindWithDn is the next:

```
*org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 52e, v1db1*
```

And 52e code interpretation which I read on the LDAP wiki is not entirely correct because is launching both typing a existing username and nonexistent username.

I'm refering to:

*NOTE: Returns when username is valid but password/credential is invalid. Will prevent most other errors from being displayed as noted.*

Not for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer for my question.

I got it specifying user-Search property in the bindAuthentication. Previously I had tested the userSearch option without including base directory (first parameter). So, almost for me, it's mandatory and let the authentication works.

In code:

```
<bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
  class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
  <constructor-arg>
    <bean id="bindAuthenticator" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
        <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
        <property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="userSearch"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>OU=My Company,DC=domain,DC=subdomain</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>(sAMAccountName={0})</value>
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
    <property name="searchSubtree">
        <value>true</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Perhaps I can help someone with a similar issue.

pD: Another option would be use the specified ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider

```
 <bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="domain.subdomain" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://host:port" />
    <property name="convertSubErrorCodesToExceptions" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

It seems to work fine too.